# Want to know currently executing test/class name of pytest from normal py script

Tags: python, pytest

1. Have A.py contains only fixtures and classes related to pytest
2. In A.py , One of fixture calls function which is in B.py (B.py in not an pytest script it's normal py script)
3. In B.py script, want to know and  check current test script name /fixture/current class of A.py

Based on current test name in A.py  I need to execute some instructions in B.py script

4. Is there any solution?
   Note: I don't want to edit A.py

Comment: It is not going to be a great test if the system changes behaviour when tested.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I know but we want to use  same framework for two different test environments. Before running actual tests, want to run prerequisites on different test platform.

Comment: [Cound you put your intended use case into the question? There's probably a better solution...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using inspect module, we could find test script name.
More info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

Comment: Hi manjesh-hb006, would you mind to add your solution, without the necessarity of probably dying links?